# How can one extract the names of files in a folder as text?

Tags: file, directory

For example in windows explorer?

Comment: Using any particular language/tool?

Comment: In what sense? Do you want a context menu link to copy the file name? Or a script to do it, and print out the results?

Comment: Every time the contents of a shared folder on my computer is changed, I want an email to be sent to everyone with whom I have shared the folder.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the absence of *any* further information,

```
c:> cd directory
c:> dir > files.txt
```

to write a list of files to a text file (files.txt)

EDIT: `dir /b` to simply generate the bare file names

Comment: "dir /b >files-names.txt"  <- '/b' stands for "bare listing"

Comment: Thanks, Brian. So this cannot be done in Windows, only in DOS?

Comment: Just open a command prompt in Windows (Start->Run... and launch 'cmd.exe')

Answer (score 7):

For just the file names:

```
c:\dir /b > files.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you care about distinguishing files and directories or not. The following will  write the names of files in the current directory to `listing.txt`.

In DOS:

```
C:\> IF EXIST listing.txt ERASE listing.txt
C:\> FOR %I IN (*.*) DO (ECHO %~nxI) >>listing.txt
```

In any [Bourne-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell#Descendants) shell:

```
machine$ rm listing.txt
machine$ for f in *; do [ -f $f ] && echo "$f" >> listing.txt ; done
```

or:

```
machine$ find . -type f -depth 1 -print > listing.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

For a unix environment, `cd mydirectory && ls > filelist.txt`

Comment: note: ls is smart enough to know when it's being piped.  so it doesn't give the normal information that it would if you ran it directly from the console.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking C# then the following will return the full path in an array of strings:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
```

To get the filenames:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In python! It takes the path as an arguement.

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = sys.argv[1]

    dir = os.listdir(path)
    for fname in dir:
        print fname
```

Answer (score 0):

To add some additional generic flavor, in a PHP one-liner, how about:

```
<?php file_put_contents("listing.txt", implode(PHP_EOL, glob('*')));
```